# Why did Georgi make that proposal?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-queens-gambit

In *The Queen's Gambit* S01E04 (*Middle Game*), Georgi sighs and offers to adjourn the game (after 5 hours), seeing that Beth is tired.

Why did he do that?

He had a clear advantage on a player that was not correctly prepared for the game, was it out of sportsmanship?

Comment: I am surprised by the downvote(s). Beth is clearly distracting the young boy so I lean on the side of him being infatuated with her (and US culture), and generally speaking, being a proper person (and playing straight pure chess) but this is maybe just an impression.

Comment: Weird downvote, the question is good but most of it is hidden behind spoiler tags... perhaps you should edit it so _something_ is not a big spoiler.

Comment: @Luciano: I was wondering about that tonight, actually - and was about to open a question on Meta with a proposal to treat movie spoilers differently from TV series spoilers. IMHO movie spoilers are not that useful in the **body** of the question because if someone sees a tag and a non-spoiler question, they have either seen the movie or not. This is very much different from TV series where a spoiler about something in S04 may impact those who are currently in S02 and did not get there yet → the watching pace is different. In the case of that question, I really did not want to spoil anything.

Comment: Please do not remove the spoilers for those who have not seen the series yet. (I rolled back such an edit)

Comment: @Paulie_D: please see https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/there-should-be-a-better-distinction-warning-for-spoilers-advice-in-the-help-cen

Comment: @Paulie_D: also - this IS a spoiler - the whole series is based on the behavior of players, very different from player to player (have you watched it?)

Comment: @Paulie_D re: https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/whats-the-policy-on-spoilers - I completely agree for movies. This is what I said in my question and comment. I completely disagree for series: how would you feel being in S02 if I told you, answering to your question "why does John gives money in S02E04" with "because it is revealed in S04 that he is the true villain"

Comment: @Paulie_D: fair point, my example was incorrect. A better one would be (in the question) "Why does John gives away money in S02E04 since (this obviously suggests as he is the true villain in S04)" (the () part should be in spoilers, in the question). In a movie there could be no spoilers because someone has obviously seen it (or does not care by clicking)

Comment: In any case, your question *needs to make sense* without the spoiler blocks. Granted, I haven't seen the show, but really...it simply doesn't. Until that is fixed, I'm afraid the spoiler blocks need to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing a single game of chess for five hours can be very grueling.  Georgi is also one of the first players we've seen Beth play where her win (or loss) wasn't quick.  It's also established (I can't remember before or after this scene) that Russian players will use adjournments to consult other players.  We're not explicitly shown, but it's possible that Georgi also used his adjournment to consult others for help.

The scene also takes the chance to show us what an adjournment looks like so that when it's used later it's not needed to explain it to the audience.